# Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\n\n\n\n\n\n<!'

Tags: python, excel, pandas, parsing, data-science

what I doing wrong. I tried to parse Excel file from my Github, buthave an error: `Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\n\n\n\n\n\n<!`. I did that manupulations in Spyder on my laptop and in Google Colab and get the same sad result. I am beginner at Github, maybe I`ve done something wrong with my .xlsx and it reading incorrect?

```
import pandas as pd
import requests as rq
import io
from io import BytesIO

put_k_ses = 'https://github.com/valeriigamaley/Kosh-Agach-SPS-MLDS/blob/024eb349c40174edbcd55e09e70f7fbc685c8ca6/GenInsolKoshAgachSPS.xlsx'
data1 = rq.get(put_k_ses).content
dannye_gener = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(data1)) 
print (dannye_gener)
```

**Error** looks like that:

```
XLRDError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-85891c30428a> in <module>()
      3 # путь к файлу с данными по инсоляции и генерации
      4 data1 = rq.get(put_k_ses).content
----> 5 dannye_gener = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(data1))
      6 print (dannye_gener)

9 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/util/_decorators.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    294                 )
    295                 warnings.warn(msg, FutureWarning, stacklevel=stacklevel)
--> 296             return func(*args, **kwargs)
    297 
    298         return wrapper

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py in read_excel(io, sheet_name, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, parse_dates, date_parser, thousands, comment, skipfooter, convert_float, mangle_dupe_cols)
    302 
    303     if not isinstance(io, ExcelFile):
--> 304         io = ExcelFile(io, engine=engine)
    305     elif engine and engine != io.engine:
    306         raise ValueError(

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py in __init__(self, path_or_buffer, engine)
    865         self._io = stringify_path(path_or_buffer)
    866 
--> 867         self._reader = self._engines[engine](self._io)
    868 
    869     def __fspath__(self):

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/excel/_xlrd.py in __init__(self, filepath_or_buffer)
     20         err_msg = "Install xlrd >= 1.0.0 for Excel support"
     21         import_optional_dependency("xlrd", extra=err_msg)
---> 22         super().__init__(filepath_or_buffer)
     23 
     24     @property

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/excel/_base.py in __init__(self, filepath_or_buffer)
    349             # N.B. xlrd.Book has a read attribute too
    350             filepath_or_buffer.seek(0)
--> 351             self.book = self.load_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)
    352         elif isinstance(filepath_or_buffer, str):
    353             self.book = self.load_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/pandas/io/excel/_xlrd.py in load_workbook(self, filepath_or_buffer)
     33         if hasattr(filepath_or_buffer, "read"):
     34             data = filepath_or_buffer.read()
---> 35             return open_workbook(file_contents=data)
     36         else:
     37             return open_workbook(filepath_or_buffer)

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/xlrd/__init__.py in open_workbook(filename, logfile, verbosity, use_mmap, file_contents, encoding_override, formatting_info, on_demand, ragged_rows)
    160         formatting_info=formatting_info,
    161         on_demand=on_demand,
--> 162         ragged_rows=ragged_rows,
    163         )
    164     return bk

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/xlrd/book.py in open_workbook_xls(filename, logfile, verbosity, use_mmap, file_contents, encoding_override, formatting_info, on_demand, ragged_rows)
     89         t1 = time.clock()
     90         bk.load_time_stage_1 = t1 - t0
---> 91         biff_version = bk.getbof(XL_WORKBOOK_GLOBALS)
     92         if not biff_version:
     93             raise XLRDError("Can't determine file's BIFF version")

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/xlrd/book.py in getbof(self, rqd_stream)
   1269             bof_error('Expected BOF record; met end of file')
   1270         if opcode not in bofcodes:
-> 1271             bof_error('Expected BOF record; found %r' % self.mem[savpos:savpos+8])
   1272         length = self.get2bytes()
   1273         if length == MY_EOF:

/usr/local/lib/python3.7/dist-packages/xlrd/book.py in bof_error(msg)
   1263         if DEBUG: print("reqd: 0x%04x" % rqd_stream, file=self.logfile)
   1264         def bof_error(msg):
-> 1265             raise XLRDError('Unsupported format, or corrupt file: ' + msg)
   1266         savpos = self._position
   1267         opcode = self.get2bytes()

XLRDError: Unsupported format, or corrupt file: Expected BOF record; found b'\n\n\n\n\n\n<!'
```

Comment: You may need to tell `read_excel` to expect an XLSX file. It will probably default to XLS when not passed a filename.

Answer (score 0):

Since you're passing in a memory stream, you'll need to pass in an engine:

> If io is not a buffer or path, engine must be set to identify io.

([the docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.read_excel.html#))

```
dannye_gener = pd.read_excel(io.BytesIO(data1), engine="openpyxl")
```

Since you do have a byte buffer (`data1`), though, you could just do

```
dannye_gener = pd.read_excel(data1)
```

Comment: pandas might be able to handle the raw url too

Comment: Sure, it might. For the sake of example, let's assume OP elided some elaborate `requests` authentication code which Pandas can't deal with :)

Comment: that's a good point

Comment: Of course, I try a easy way to read a raw url 'raw=true', but it didn't work and give error "http not found" :c